# Name.NameCtrl PresenceEnabled in Visual Studio debug window

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer, debugging, lync

I'm using the following code to get contact presence on a web page:

```
nameCtrl = new ActiveXObject("Name.NameCtrl.1");
if (nameCtrl && nameCtrl.PresenceEnabled) {
    presenceEnabled = true;
    nameCtrl.OnStatusChange = onPresenceStatusChange;
    // ...
}
```

It works perfectly when I run it in VS but only from a separate Internet Explorer window, doesn't work in the debug IE window started by Visual Studio (so I cannot debug JS code). What happens is that initially nameCtrl.PresenceEnabled is set to true (just after creating ActivexObject) and then is changed to false, I don't get any status updates and all GetStatus calls return 1.

Any ideas how to make it work in Visual Studio?

I'm targeting IE and Lync.

Answer (score 1):

The whole nameCtrl turns out to be very difficult to debug. Some things to check:

If the plugin doesn’t work in IE11, but works if you change the document mode to IE10, it is because IE11 no longer recognizes ActiveXObject as a property of the window object. (see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

No javascript errors but nothing seems to be working? For this to work, you may need to go into Internet Explorer’s Internet Options menu and add your domain (or localhost) as a trusted domain.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't help. The site (localhost) is already in trusted domains list. And I'm using IE10. On another machine with IE11 it works OK from VS debug window, so it might be the case that it just doesn't work when debugging with IE10.